# How can I express the sentence: "Every human has exactly two legs" in First Order Logic

Tags: first-order-logic

How can I express the sentence: "Every human has exactly two legs" in First Order Logic without using the number 2 like the example "$(\forall x)(Human(x) \wedge NumberOfLegs(x, 2))$" and use something like $Leg(x,l)$ and $=$

Comment: you can try saying something like "every x, if x is human, then it has more than one leg and less than three"

Comment: Mimick the [Uniqueness quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall x\left[H\left(x\right)\to\exists u\exists v\left[u\neq v\wedge L\left(x,u\right)\wedge L\left(x,v\right)\wedge\forall z\left[L\left(x,z\right)\to\left(z=u\vee z=v\right)\right]\right]\right]$$
Here $H(x)$ stands for "$x$ is human" and $L(x,y)$ for "$y$ is a leg of $x$".

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall x (H(x) \to \exists y \exists z (y \neq z \land \forall w(L(x,w) \leftrightarrow (w =y \lor w=z)))$$